# How to set datetime field in the symphony 3 for update or insert data?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set the date and time field in the symfony 3.4 in this way:

```
$eventProject = new $eventProject();

$eventProject->setDateFrom('2018-05-09');
```

when I save the values, It is giving me error like:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'dateFrom' can
  not be null
In ConversionException.php line 95:

  Could not convert PHP value '2018-05-09' of type 'string' to type 'datetime
  '. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime
```

I could not understand what is wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use PHP's `DateTime` object to set the date.

```
$eventProject = new $eventProject();
$date = new \DateTime('2018-05-09');
$eventProject->setDateFrom($date);
```

This also means that you have to work with `DateTime` when retrieving the date.

```
$date = $eventProject->getDate();
var_dump($date->format("Y-m-d")); 
//string(10) "2018-05-09"
```

Be sure to use `format` on a retrieved `DateTime` object when you want to get the date as a string.

This is more about how the `eventProject` class/entity is written and not something that is forced by `Symfony`. That being said it is quite a common way to work with time in PHP projects. In the beginning it can seem a little awkward but as you get used to it you will find [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) to be pretty handy.